# Location of .NET ToolStrip Standard Icons

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

Where can I find images for Microsoft ToolStrip icons, such as: New, Open, Save, Save All, Print, Next, Previous, Play, Undo, etc?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Microsoft provides a zip file of all images.  You can find it at file://c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\common7\vs2010imagelibrary\1033\vs2010imagelibrary.zip

Comment: Exactly, one small note: it does not exist in the Express editions

Comment: Wow, this file is great!  It even has all the animations: searching, file copying, deleting, etc.

Comment: Does not exist in VS 2012 (https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/758881/image-library-missing-from-visual-studio-2012)

Comment: On a Windows 7 64-bit system the VS2010ImageLibrary.zip file is under the "Program Files (x86)" directory "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\VS2010ImageLibrary\1033."

Answer (score 58):

If for some reason you can't find the image archive, you can download it from here:

[Visual Studio Image Library](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35825)

You should see the following download modal (screenshot 5/4/2023):

[image: Download modal]

Comment: Here (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35825) you can download the latest Visual Studio Image Library package that contains VS 2012 images (20 MB) and VS 2013 too (290 MB).

Comment: The download page seems to be broken. There is no way to select the downloads you want.

Comment: Downloads page only allows you to download the EULA.

Comment: I see EULAs for older versions but an image library zip file for the latest version. I uploaded a screenshot for what I'm seeing.